# SQL Server Sync Jobs Betwen Primary and Secondary Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, disaster-recovery

I am setting up a Standby Server for disaster recovery and high availability reasons. My product relies heavily on SQL Jobs, as such, these jobs need to exist (Disabled) on the Standby server.

I have the database replication setup, however I can't find information on techniques for syncing jobs between two servers.

Does anybody do this, and what techniques can you suggest?

I'm currently using SQL Server 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSIS there's an SSIS task that can transfer all jobs, or just specific jobs.  You can tell it to overwrite the jobs, or fail if they exist, and handle the job deletion your self.  Schedule this as a job to run nightly, or make it a part of your job release process to run this job after a job has been changed.

You'll want to add a SQL task after the jobs have been transferred to disable them using the procedures in the msdb database.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, does a similar task exist for logins and users?

Comment: For Logins yes.  Users are stored within the database and will come across with when the database is restored.